# Stop bots from crawling old links with extensions

Tags: robots.txt, web-crawlers, googlebot

I've recently switched to MVC3 which is extension-less for the URL's, but Google and Bing have a wealth of links that they are crawling which no longer exist.

So I'm trying to find out if there is a way to format robots.txt (or by some other method) to tell google/bing that any link that ends in an extension isn't a valid link...  Is this possible?

On pages that I'm concerned about a User having saved as a fav I'm displaying a 404 page that lists the links to take once they are redirected to the new page (I decided to not just redirect them as I don't want to maintain these forever).  For Google/Bing sake I do have the canonical tag in the header.

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
Disallow: /*.*
```

EDIT:  I just added the 3rd line (in text above) and it APPEARS to do what I'm wanting.  Allow a path, but disallow a file.  Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: Don't use that Allow. A draft spec had Allow overriding Disallow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the "Allow" directive in your robots.txt does nothing as robots spider everything by default.

Blocking robots from `*.*` is probably OK in some situations, but remember that you are blocking *every* URL that simply contains a dot. A more reliable method may be blocking individual extensions (if there are not too many) eg `*.html` and `*.php` on separate lines.

The preferred method of moving to new pages is a 301 Redirect, which should always be used unless technically difficult. (Although they are 'permanent' redirects you do not need to maintain them forever: a few months is fine.) It's better for users too, as they get a seamless experience.